# Как отследить событие change всех input'ов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть форма вида:

```
<form type="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="text">
</form>
```

Нужно, что бы при выборе пользователем одного файла, подгружалось новое поле для загрузки еще одного файла. Проблема в том, что с данным кодом событие `change` отслеживается только на первом `input` формы. То есть новые поля формы добавляются на страницу только в том случае, если изменять 1ый input.

```
var inputs = $('#formId :input');
$('#formId :input').change(function () {
    if (fileInputs.length < 4) {
        var content = '<input type="file" name="text' +
        (fileInputs.length + 1) + '">';
        $('#formId').append(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#formId').on("change", 'input[type="file"]', function () {
  var fileInputs = $('#formId input[type="file"]');
  if (fileInputs.length < 4) {
    var content = '<input type="file" name="text' +  (fileInputs.length + 1) + '">';
    $('#formId').append(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId" type="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="text">
</form>
```

Тут дело в *делегировании* при назначении обработчика события `change`. В коде ответа, обработчик назначается элементу `#formId`, с указанием, что выполнять его надо для событий, которые произошли на элементах `input[type="file"]`. В таком случае не важно, существуют эти инпуты в момент назначения обработчика или будут созданы позднее.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ. Но не могли бы вы чуть подробнее объяснить, в чём  тут загвоздка? По логике  код практически одинаковый, но у вас работает, а у меня нет :)

Comment: @RomanAndreev Добавил.

Comment: Igor, я правильно понял, что всегда когда мы работаем с динамически создаваемыми элементами на странице - нужно использовать форму записи как в вашем ответе?

Comment: @RomanAndreev Когда требуется, чтобы события обрабатывались одинаково для существующих элементов и созданных позже, - да.